# CkEditor LITE plugin couldn't find jQuery

Tags: jquery, plugins, ckeditor4

I add **LITE** plugin in ckeditor4 by downloading it from https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/lite and add extracted folder to plugins folder of ckeditor and then I add **lite** to extraPlugin in config.js file

`config.extraPlugins = ['lite']`

and I also add jQueryPath in config.js file

`config.lite.jQueryPath = 'js/jquery.min.js';`

But it can't find JQuery:
plugin.js?t=LAHF:8865 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: I also have this error

ckeditor.js:267 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'icons')
    at CKEDITOR.resourceManager.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:267:254)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I download LITE plugin code from GitLab and add it to CKEditor plugins folder and the problem was fixed.